# Creating a keyboard shortcut for Browser's AutoFill feature

Tags: shortcut, web-browser

I'd like to create a keyboard shortcut for the **Edit > AutoFill > Passwords...** or for almost the same path just with the right-click on an input field (in Sonoma).

The problem is when I set it in the **Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts ...** it works, for example, in Notes.app or the Browsers' URL bar but not in the input fields on webpages which would be the main use case.

Comment: Where do you see the menu Edit > Autofill > Passwords… I've checked Mojave & Ventura & don't see it, just Edit > AutoFill Form

Comment: Ohh, then it might have changed in Sonoma. I'll update the question, thanks.

Comment: Can you show us pictures, menu item [Safari & Notes] & your key command setup? I can't imagine the command structure has changed much, so something is odd somewhere.

Comment: Here are them: [menu item](https://postimg.cc/k6sxwrpr) / [right click context menu](https://postimg.cc/9RCdGX1t)

Comment: Hmm… yup. It should show the key command there in the menu too. Are you using full stops [periods] or a true ellipsis? Some OSes care, some don't, with no real pattern. Does the menu item appear in more than one place? Otherwise you don't need to try create a 'path' to it.  BTW, it's never been possible to call a right click menu item by key command. It has to be in a 'real' menu.